# Can someone please explain the noun phrase "El de"?

Tags: gramática

I've come across the following sentence:

> El de mi hermano también.
>
> My brother, too.

What purpose is served by "el de"? Why not simply say:

> Mi hermano también.

UPDATE: The above example is missing some context, but I was too unfamiliar with Spanish to realize it until RSanchez posted an answer.

The missing context is that there is a conversation between two individuals:

> Person1: Mi coche es viejo.
>
> Person2: El de mi hermano también.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*El de* can be translated by just the use of the genitive:

> My brother's too.

In the Spanish construction, the article works as a pronoun; *el* means *el coche*, in this case. Using the noun instead of the article/pronoun:

> El coche de mi hermano también.

Answer (score 4):

*El de mi hermano* means:

> The one of my brother

Your question lacks some context to know what are we referring to with *el de* or *the one*. There could be some cases where *el de mi hermano, también* translates to *my brother, too*, but there's insufficient information to know if that's the case or not.

Comment: I updated my original question to include some additional context. Thanks @RSanchez.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it would translate as "that of", i.e. "that [thing] of my brother".

But in English you use 's for possession, that's why you don't find a 1:1 relation.